# Gapi.iframes does not work since Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, google-api-js-client

I have an issue with [ng-gapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-gapi) since Angular 2. I need to display the google "Managed configurations iframe" and I followed the steps from the [Google developper doc](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/managed-configurations-iframe#iframe_events) it worked on the angularJS however when i tried it with Angular 2+ it didn't.

```
this.gapiService.onLoad().subscribe((result:any)=> {
        gapi.load("gapi.iframes", function(){           

            var iframeContainer = document.getElementById('iframecontainer');

            var context = gapi.iframes.getContext();

            var options = {
              'url': this.url,
              'where': iframeContainer,
              'attributes': { 
                style: 'height:1200px', 
                scrolling: 'yes'
              }
            }

            var iframe = context.openChild(options);

            iframe.register('onconfigupdated', function(o) {
                console.log(o);
                this.data.mcmId = o.mcmId;                    
                this.dialogRef.close(this.data);
            } , function(data) { 
                return true; 
            });

            iframe.register('onconfigdeleted', function(o) {
                console.log(o);
                this.data.mcmId = null;                    
                this.dialogRef.close(this.data);
            } , function(data) { 

                return true; 

            });


        });
    });
```

the problem is that iframes doesn't exist in GAPI i think, and i need to render the iframe with Gapi to catch the events "onconfigupdated" and "onconfigdeleted".

Answer (score 1):

So it's expected that you don't receive the events from the iframe if you don't use the gapi JS library, you need to use the gapi JS library to be able to receive the events.

If the ng-gapi wrapper doesn't support the iframe then you could either extend it to support the iframe or create your own custom wrapper specifically for your use case.